# Como fazer uma soma em Lambda com lógica recursiva usando sucessor e antecessor?

Tags: python, expressões-lambda, recursão, lógica

Estou tentando montar uma Soma com lógica de recursividade usando apenas sucessor e antecessor em Lambda. Mas não estão conseguindo...

No caso:

```
suc = λx.x+1

ant = λx.x-1
```

Fiz já algo do tipo:

```
{λx.[λy.(x-1)+(y+1)][λy.(x-1)+(y+1)]}
```

Mas não sei se isso está certo... Não tem código de erro, pois eu não cheguei a implementar, estou querendo montar a logica.

Comment: Olá bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Amigo recomendo que leia o Tour do Stack Overflow, irá te ajudar a ser mais claro em suas perguntas. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Sua pergunta é sobre python ou lambda-calculus?

Comment: Tanto faz na verdade, pois é possível se fazer em Python.

Comment: Teve algum código de erro? Ou o resultado não foi o esperado?

Comment: Não, pois eu não cheguei a implementar eu estou querendo montar a logica.

Comment: Escrever funções lambda recursivas é um pouco difícil, já que as funções não tem nome. Você vai precisar usar um operador de ponto fixo ou trocar a sua definição de números (se vc usar numerais de church ao invés de inteiros de Python fica mais fázil fazer a soma)

Answer (score 2):

Conforme a resposta no SO em inglês:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481692/can-a-lambda-function-call-itself-recursively-in-python

É possível montar uma soma lógica (ou outros algoritmos) com recursividade utilizando funções [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) em Python.

Um ponto importante sobre funções recursivas é que, obrigatóriamente, elas devem ter uma condição de parada, ou seja, em algum momento, o algoritmo deve retornar para evitar um looping infinito (referências no final da resposta).

Conforme a resposta acima, existem várias formas para criar essas expressões.

Os exemplos abaixo, efetuam (recursivamente) o cálculo:

```
x=10
soma = 10 + 9 + 8 + 7 + 6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1 = 55
```

---

### Exemplos:

**a) Atribuir um nome à função `lambda` criada (mais fácil):**

```
soma = lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else x+soma(x-1)
```

Resultado:

```
>>> soma = lambda x: 1 if x == 1 else x+soma(x-1)
>>> soma(10)
55
```

A variável `soma` recebe o valor de uma função anônima (`lambda`)
e retorna caso o parâmetro da função seja `1` (condição de parada).

Caso o valor seja maior que `1`, ela soma o valor do parâmetro `x`
ao resultado de uma chamada recursiva com parâmetro `x-1`,
feita através da referência armazenada na variável `soma`.

---

**b) Utilizando uma função auxiliar:**

```
def soma(f, *p, **kw):
    return f(f, *p, **kw)

soma( (lambda fr, x: 1 if x == 1 else x + fr(fr, x-1)), 10 )
```

Resultado:

```
>>> soma( (lambda fr, x: 1 if x == 1 else x + fr(fr, x-1)), 10 )
55
```

Este tipo de função é conhecido como **Combinador de ponto fixo** (ver referências) ou [Y-combinator de Lemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347984/does-python-have-no-need-for-the-y-combinator).

A função auxiliar `soma` recebe 3 parâmetros:

- `f` - irá receber uma função anônima
- `*p` - recebe uma lista de parâmetros posicionais
- `**kw` - recebe uma lista de parâmetros nomeados

consultar: [Keyword Arguments - Documentação Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments)  (em inglês)

Ao chamar a função `soma`, o primeiro parâmetro informado é uma função `lambda` que recebe 2 parâmetros: a própria função (em `fr`) e o valor `10`.

A chamada recursiva ocorre em: `x + fr(fr, x-1)` e, posteriormente em `return f(f, *p, **kw)`.

A condição de parada é a mesma que a anterior.

---

**c) Apenas com funções anônimas (mais complexo):**

```
(lambda f1: lambda v1: f1(f1, v1))(lambda f, x: 1 if x == 1 else x+f(f, x-1))(10)
```

Resultado:

```
>>> (lambda f1: lambda v1: f1(f1, v1))(lambda f, x: 1 if x == 1 else x+f(f, x-1))(10)
55
```

Esta função também é uma variação do *Y-combinator de Lemmy*.

Dividindo a linha do comando em 3 partes:

*1)* A primeira parte equivale à função auxiliar do exemplo (**b**) acima.

O parâmetro `f1` recebe a função do item 2 (abaixo) e o parâmetro `v1` irá receber o valor `10`, a partir da chamada recursiva `f1(f1, v1)`:

```
(lambda f1: lambda v1: f1(f1, v1))
```

*2)* A segunda parte é a função que executa o cálculo:

```
(lambda f, x: 1 if x == 1 else x+f(f, x-1))
```

*3)* A terceira parte é valor 10, que será enviado ao parâmetro `v1`, e, posteriormente a `x`:

```
(10)
```

Para facilitar o entendimento deste exemplo, o comando é equivalente ao exemplo (**a**) da seguinte forma:

```
f1 = lambda f, x: 1 if x == 1 else x+f(f, x-1)
v1 = 10
f1(f1, v1)
```

---

Para os testes, foi utilizado [Python 2.7.11](https://www.python.org/).

**Importante:** conforme as referências, este tipo de de código tem utilidade acadêmica e, provavelmente, o uso em ambientes de produção não é recomendado.

Referências:

[Wikilivros - Algoritmos e Estruturas de Dados/Recursividade](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algoritmos_e_Estruturas_de_Dados/Recursividade)

[Wikipedia - Recursividade - ciência da computação](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

[Wikipedia - Cálculo lambda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%A1lculo_lambda)

[Wikipedia - Combinador de ponto fixo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinador_de_ponto_fixo)